# How to listen for an event from DTE object when a new line is added to code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I am writing a visual studio extension (VSIX) that will be logging the code statements in database. So I need a event raised when a code statement is added to code in active window;

Comment: Checkout [ITextBuffer2.ChangedOnBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextbuffer2.changedonbackground?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

Comment: Try to get the instance DTE.Events.TextEditorEvents(EnvDTE.TextDocument) and then use the TextEditorEvents.LineChanged event